# checking whether $\log(x+1):(0,+\infty)\to (0,+\infty)$ is a function, then whether it is onto or 1-1 or both

Tags: functions, logarithms

$f:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}_+, f(x)=\log(x+1)$

How to start? Should i start computing $f(1), f(2) ....$ and then plotting them on the graph

Comment: Plotting a graph of the function will certainly give you some good intuition. Can you write down an inverse to your function? Do you know why this would help?

Comment: How do you define $\log$? As the inverse of $10^x$? I also think the title should be changed to "checking if $\log(x+1):(0,+\infty)\to (0,+\infty)$ is onto  or 1-1 or both"

Answer (score 0):

Basically we have a set of positive real numbers as the domain and same for codomain.
It is certainly a one one function as in log graph every value of x will give a unique y value.(Plot and SEE!)
This function will also be onto as all real numbers on the x axis will give a different y value as the graph is not symmetrical and is always increasing .So also onto.
Hope you get the idea :)